# Android views within tabs method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I am creating an application where each tab has different screens to switch between. Originally I was going to have each tab show a different activity but from what I have read, it seems that is a bad way of doing it.

So I have been using an xml file which has the layout for each screen all in the one file. And I use Java to program which to display each screen required and hide the ones I don't need. The problem I have with this approach is it means all my Java is one file, and all my XML is in one file. Could someone explain to me a better way of doing this as I am pretty sure there must be a better way. My activity has many screens and its getting an eye sore scrolling through all this code at once, as the more screens I add, the larger the code is getting.

Ideally I would like to have the code for each screen in its own Java class, and the layouts for each screen in their own xml files and just switch between these.

To give you example of my code

```
<TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#92c223" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
XML CODE FOR LAYOUT GOES IN HERE. EACH NEW SCREEN IS CONTAINED WITHIN THESE LAYOUTS.
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

<TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_weight="0"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
</FrameLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

Then in my Java code, I switch between tabs using

```
if ("home".equals(tabId)) {
                tab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tab4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tab5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and when switching between screens within an activity, when user clicks a button in that activity, I use on click listener and do this

```
        tab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cvv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing this, and would be grateful if someone would give me suggestions.

Another problem is, as its all in one activity, whenever I hit the back button, it just exits the application. Would prefer to have it so when they hit back, it goes back to previous screen.

Comment: Also should add other problem, as its all in one activity, whenever I hit the back button, it just exits the application. Would prefer to have it so when they hit back, it goes back to previous screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'better way' is giving each tab an activity of its own. Why did you dismiss this approach in your first paragraph? This is exactly what a `TabHost` was designed for.

What I usually do is subclass `TabActivity`. In its `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, I do the following once for each tab:

```
tabHost.addTab(
    tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
    .setIndicator("Tab 1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1))
    .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class))
);
```

Then you develop each `Tab#Activity` in an independent file. It's nice and modular. Switching between tabs is handled by the library. You don't need to worry about all that.

Within your tabs, you can capture the back button by overriding the `onKeyDown` method in your inner activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Do your thing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I have done  that in one of my projects as I have 5 tabs. However each tab has many different screens to access within that. And if I access a new activity from within the tab, the Tabs disappear which is why I found that method does not seem to work.

Comment: So you have multiple screens per tab. But why does this mean a `TabHost` with separate activities doesn't work? At least it cuts down on the clutter. Within each tab you can still use your `setVisibility` trick with the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that after you posted, I could have done that. Don't know why it did't occur to me before. So now I have the 5 activities which sets up an xml file which contains multiple layouts, and just use the visibility trick within it. Lot easier split up among 5 xml files and classes then one file lol.

One other question tho, is there anyway I can set up the back button, to go back to previous screen as at present it just exits application as activities all contained within the tab host.

Comment: Try overriding the `onKeyDown` method. See the extra info I put in my answer.